# Swift 4 - How could I get a result(Dictionary and data) with completion handler help of typealias

Tags: swift, alamofire, response, completionhandler, type-alias

I'm having a little confused in completion handlers with typealias

I have created a **typealias** that having result,status,data .Here is how I am creating it:

```
typealias Success = (_ result:Dictionary<String, Any>, _ Status:Bool,_ Data:Data) -> Void
```

I have a method with URL , Param , fail alert and completion handler.I have pass the typealias to completion handler. Here is the method

```
private func callApi(apiURL:ApiURL, param:[String: Any]?, failAlert:Bool, completionHandler: @escaping Success) {

        var url = "\(AppBaseUrl)\(apiURL.rawValue)"

        var params:[String:Any] = [:]
        var methods:HTTPMethod = .get
        if param != nil {
            params = param!
            methods = .post
            self.printParam(param: params)
        }
        self.apiCallKR(url: url, methods: methods, params: params, failAlert: failAlert, completionHandler: Success)
    }
```

I got error like this

> **Cannot convert value of type 'Success.Type' (aka '((Dictionary, Bool, Data) -> ()).Type'**

How to **pass completionHandler(KRResult.result, KRResult.Status,response.data!)** to success Typealias

```
func apiCallKR(url:String, methods:HTTPMethod, params:[String:Any],  failAlert:Bool, completionHandler: @escaping Success) {
         let header = ["User-ID":Extensions.getUserID(),"Auth-Key":Extensions.getToken()]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: methods, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
            KRLog("Response: \n\(response)")

            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if statusCode == 200, let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                   AppDetail.stopIndicator()
                    let KRResult =  self.jsonResponseValidation(sender: json, failAlert: failAlert)
                    completionHandler(KRResult.result, KRResult.Status,response.data!)

                }else {
                    completionHandler([:], false, response.data!)
                    AppDetail.stopIndicator()
                    AppDetail.showToast(toastText: AlertText(.textAlertJsonFormatMismatch), type: .fail, handler: nil)
                }
}
}
}
```

Comment: completionHandler(KRResult.result, KRResult.Status,response.data!) first param returning dictionary , bool, data as mentioned in typealais, can you confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
self.apiCallKR(url: url, methods: methods, params: params, failAlert: failAlert, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```